# Application is closing unexpectedly when user getting into the Geofence or dwelling into the Geofence

Tags: android, google-maps, geofencing

I have implemented Geofence service in my android application to notify the user when user is entering, dwelling or exiting that Geofence. In my implementation, I am able to add geofence at any place by long pressing on specific location.
But when user get into that Geofence or Geofence is add such that user is already in Geofence, app unexpectedly crash.

How can I solve this issue?

Here is my **GeofenceBroadcastReceiver.java** class.

```
public class GeoFenceBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "GeoFenceBroadcastReceiv";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving
        // an Intent broadcast.
        Toast.makeText(context, "Geofence triggered...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);

        if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: Error receiving geofence event...");
            return;
        }

        List<Geofence> geofenceList = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringGeofences();
        for (Geofence geofence: geofenceList) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: " + geofence.getRequestId());
        }

        Location location = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringLocation();
        int transitionType = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();

        switch (transitionType) {
            case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER:
                Toast.makeText(context, "GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL:
                Toast.makeText(context, "GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT:
                Toast.makeText(context, "GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }

        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question and provide your log.

Comment: Note that several of the geofencing api calls you are making _can_ return null according to documentation: `fromIntent`, `getTriggeringGeofences`, `getTriggeringLocation`.

Comment: My machine is not supporting android emulator and app is crashing when user is moving. So, it is not possible for me to provide the log when app is crashing. Is there any other way to test? Please suggest me.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device - be sure to uninstall app (assuming it was installed from store) - then use studio as you would with an emulator.

Answer (score 0):

There are cases where geofencingEvent returns null , so you can implement a countermeasure for that.